# How to create a temp table in teradata SQL Assstant

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

How to create a Temp table in teradata SQL Assistant?
I have a query that is running very slow and I want to optimize it by creating a temp table.

What I want is to be able to drop and re-create a temp table with the same name automatically anytime the query is executed in Teradata SQL assistant.
Any help would be appreciated please.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a volatile table and imbibe both creation of volatile table and your query within a begin transaction and end transaction

```
BT;
create volatile table xxx;

your query

ET;
```

Comment: OK I shall give it a try. Thank you